# PrimeFaces css not working

Tags: web, primefaces

I'm configuring a project with primefaces 3.3.1 and Myfaces 2.1.1. I run an simple example of showcase, but this example show text only, without CSS content. I see any examples using manually import of the css on  in xhtml, but I think that it no is a good way.

pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency

    <!-- Primefaces dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Themes PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluesky</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
   </repositories>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>meu-projeto</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.meuprojeto.servlet.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.teste</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>    <!-- 30 minutes -->
</session-config>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

My Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">

    <p:panel header="Enter your passwords">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Basic: " />
            <p:password id="nonFeedback" value="" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

    <p:spacer height="10" />

    <p:panel header="Match Mode">
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:commandButton id="saveButton" update="matchGrid" value="Save" />
    </p:panel>

</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Then did  Project > Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java build path entries and add all jars. So, in Library project have all jars.

Comment: look at this http://ovaraksin.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/bundled-primefaces-themes.html , maybe will give you some idea...

Comment: I used page of showcase but edit her. I edit me question and add more info. Thanks

Comment: Hi again, could you show us the complete web.xml ?

Comment: Of course! Added in the question.

Comment: You've mapped your faces servlet to *.jsf is that the extension that you are using for your XHTML pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui
```

in xhtml page.

I change to:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui
```

and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Faces Servlet mapping in your web.xml file  from:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The way you have it configured prevents the Faces Servlet from handling your JSF pages.

Comment: which application server are you using? have you tried a maven clean before redeploying your app?

Comment: I'm using tomcat7. Yep, I did clan all projects (eclipse), clean install (maven2) and in tomcat7, remove/add project, clean and publish.

Comment: Do you have any errors on your browser console (firebug or other?)  like 404 while requesting css and js files?

Comment: Initially I using primefaces 3.4-SNAPSHOT, and this version have showing error "css not found" but when changed to 3.3 version this error no occurs.

Comment: humm that is weird could you post a screenshot of the page with the web console (in your browser) open so that I can see the network requests executed by the browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15136/discussion-between-ufasoli-and-vctlzac)